# Help in understanding the conditions for the following asymptote

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> On integrating, we get ...
>   $$
> y^3+3x^2y+4x^3=c\tag{5}
> $$
>   which is the required family of cubics.
>
> From (5) we get
>   $$
> (y+x)(y^2-xy+4x^2)=c\tag{6}
> $$
>   The asymptotics of (6) corresponding to the factor $(x+y)$ is given by
>   \begin{align}
> x+y&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{c}{y^2-xy+4x^2}\right)
> \\
> &\frac yx \to 1
> \end{align}

[image]

My question is how did the author deduced the second limit condition to be $\frac{y}x\to1$ as shown in the image ??

Answer (score 2):

If you divide by $x^3$ on both sides in $(6)$ you get $(\frac{y}{x}+1)(\frac{y}{x}^2-\frac{y}{x}+4)=\frac{c}{x^3}$. As $x\rightarrow \infty$ the right hand side will go to $0$, so the left hand side will go to $0$ too and this means that $\frac{y}{x}$ will approach one of the roots of the polynomial $(t+1)(t^2-t+4)$, which only has the root $-1$. Thus as $x\rightarrow \infty$ it must be $\frac{y}{x} \rightarrow -1$, so I don't think the result in your text is right.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing the context, this is the result of the integation of an ODE. The solution curves of the ODE lie inside the level curves of this cubic polynomial.

If you consider points of the curve of level $c$ with very large values of $x$ and consequently $y$, then the constant $c$ will be relatively small. This means that at these large values the level curves asymptotically approximate the root sets of the factors $(x+y)=0$ and $(y^2-xy+4x^2)=0$.

For the solutions close to the roots of the first factor that means that $y(x)\approx -x$ or 
$$
y(x)=-x+u(x)
$$
with $|u|\ll |x|$ for $|x|\gg 1$. Insert that into the equation for level $c$ and consider the lowest order terms for $u$,
$$
u·(6x^2-3xu+u^2)=c
$$
Ignore third order terms and multiply with $(2x+u)$ to get
$$
u·(12x^3+O(u^2))=c(2x+u)
\\~\\\iff
u=\frac{2cx}{12x^3-c}+O(u^3)=\frac{c}{6x^2}\left(1+\frac{c}{12x^3}\right)+O(x^{-6})
$$
so that in total you get for $|x|$ sufficiently large
$$
y(x)=-x+\frac{c}{6x^2}+O(x^{-5})
$$